# POST request via requestJS to send Array of JSON Objects and image files

Tags: arrays, node.js, rest, post, requestjs

I'm building REST API with NODEjs, using Express routers and Multer middleware to handle multiple body data and files.

My endpoint route 127.0.0.1/api/postData expects: json data with fields, one of which is array of json objects (I'm having nested mongoose schema) and 2 named images (png/jpg).

I need to send Post request via cURL with the following 5-object data structure:

```
name  String
description String
usersArray  Array of json objects like:   [{"id": "123"}, {"id": "456}]
imgIcon  Png/Image    providing  /path/to/imageIcon.png
imgHeader Png/Image     providing /path/to/imageHeader.png
```

Any idea how to write this request with the help of request.js node http request library  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
request.post({
    url:'http://127.0.0.1:7777/api/postData'
    , formData: formData
    , qsStringifyOptions : {
        arrayFormat : 'brackets' // [indices(default)|brackets|repeat]
    }
}, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
 // do something...
}
```

I found three options for arrayFormat in https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs (used by https://www.npmjs.com/package/request):

```
'indices' sends in postbody: (this is the default case)
usersArray%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=a667cc8f&usersArray%5B1%5D%5Bid%5D=7c7960fb
decoded:
usersArray[0][id]=a667cc8f&usersArray[1][id]=7c7960fb

'brackets' sends in postbody:
usersArray%5B%5D%5Bid%5D=a667cc8f&usersArray%5B%5D%5Bid%5D=7c7960fb
decoded:
usersArray[][id]=a667cc8f&usersArray[][id]=7c7960fb

'repeat' sends in postbody:
usersArray%5Bid%5D=a667cc8f&usersArray%5Bid%5D=7c7960fb
decoded:
usersArray[id]=a667cc8f&usersArray[id]=7c7960fb
```

these are three different ways to serialize arrays before posting. Basically it depends on the receiving end how these need/can be formatted. In my case it helped to use 'brackets'